# Conda meta packages m2w64-toolchain needed to be installed in base environment and not virtual

Tags: python, anaconda, virtual-environment

I need to use the pymc3 module which relies on theano. However, I witnessed some weird behavior for which I could not find a solution in the documentation and from general web-search.

When using pymc3, I got several problems with missing compilers. Using multiple web searches I found that I need to install:

```
conda install -c conda-forge m2w64-toolchain_win-64    
conda install -c anaconda libpython
conda install mkl-service
```

Then pymc3 works. I would like to setup up a virtual environment. However, I would like my base environment to be clean and run my projects on virtual environments. So from a clean base, if I create a new environment, e.g. conda create -n temp python=3.7 and run the three lines above, then I get the following warning, when importing pymc3:

```
WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS functions.
```

If I instead run the line:

```
conda install -c conda-forge m2w64-toolchain_win-64
```

in my base environment and then setup a virtual environment and install these two in the venv:

```
conda install -c anaconda libpython
conda install mkl-service
```

The warning disappears.

Could someone give me an explanation of why this warning persistent if I do not run the tool-chain install in my base environment? 
Any help is appreciated. I only use Python for data analysis and I am not very knowledgeable regarding the technical-stuff.

Comment: Same problems here